# Dynamic Polymorphism explained

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I was looking for something very easy to explain about polymorphism and I found an example. But I cannot see where actually its implemented in the code and How does it do so? Can you guys help for me?

Code:

```
//a class for dynamic polymorphism
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract int Area();
}

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    private int widht = 0;
    private int lenght = 0;

    public Rectangle(int a, int b)
    {
        widht = a;
        lenght = b;
    }
    public override int Area()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Area =");
        return lenght * widht;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 9);
        double area = r.Area();
        Console.WriteLine(area);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is implemented here:

```
public override int Area()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Area =");
    return lenght * widht;
}
```

The keyword [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) says that this method is intended to be polymorphic (here it works together with the [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) keyword in the `Shape` implementation). The more obvious way to demonstrate it would be however:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 9);

Shape anUnknownShape = r;  //could be also a circle, ellipse, etc.

// here we "forget" what's the actual shape we're dealing with

double area = anUnknownShape.Area(); // Area is abstract - a polymorphic call

Console.WriteLine(area);
```

In the line marked with a second comment the call is polymorphic - having a reference of type `Shape` you don't know which `Area` would be called exactly - it may be the implementation written for a `Rectangle` or for another one, from a `Circle` or anything that subclasses `Shape`. The particular implementation will be chosen at runtime depending on the actual type.

Comment: this means that function overriding also refers to polymorphism in other words?

Comment: Exactly. "Method Overriding" would be the opposite of "Method Overloading" (Static Polymorphism).  Method Overriding is a new definition for an existing method in its child class. All objects created at run time on the heap. Actual binding is done at runtime. (late binding)

A more explanatory site:
http://www.erpgreat.com/java/static-and-dynamic-polymorphism.htm.

Comment: @AbidAli Yes, these terms are strictly related. Note the links I gave under `override` and `abstract` keywords.